# Area calculation

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, area

How could we best approach calculating the area inside $r=\cos^{2n-1}(x)+\sin(x)$, $0\leq x\leq \pi$, for $n=1,2,...$?

For $n=3$ we get the following "potato/bean" graph:

[image]

and for $n=51$ we get

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite that with the standard polar coordinate variables:

$$r=\cos^{2n-1}(\theta)+\sin(\theta),\quad 0\leq \theta\leq \pi$$

Then use the [standard formula for area of polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Integral_calculus_.28area.29):

$$A=\frac 12\int_a^b (r(\theta))^2\,d\theta$$

Do you need help going farther?

Comment: wooh... you are right! I was looking at it from a rather tedious angle!!